# What is this tree in Sydney?

Tags: species-identification, botany, trees

My family snapped this picture around Sydney, Australia. Could someone please advise what this tree is? Help! We are smittened with it :)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is a [tulipwood tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harpullia_pendula), which belongs to the species *Harpullia pendula*. As an Australian native, they're commonly used as street trees along the east coast.

[image]

[image]

More information about this tree can be found [here](https://brisbanetrees.com.au/tulipwood/).